# How can i set global get variable in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I make jsp pages and in that jsp page I have form with post method.

After form submission my get variable unset(naturally).Is there any way to keep get variable after form submission?

**my code:**

```
<form method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="10" />
                        <input type="text" name="eprice" value="3600" />
                        <input type="text" name="tprice" value="36000" />
                        <input type="text" name="type" value="request" />
<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

After form submission I need url parameters too.

Here is my url before:

`http://localhost:8080/q/product.jsp?page=2&saved=1`

After form submission get variable unsets and url will changed to:

`http://localhost:8080/q/product.jsp`

How to keep get data after form submission and still access url parameters?

In php we simply do :

`$_GET['page']=2;`

How can we handle it in JSP?

Comment: your form is of post, so URL will not have parameters

Comment: Assuming you have `jstl`, you can use the `${param}` to access the url parameters in your jsp. Use hidden field, `<input type="hidden" name="page" value="${param.page}" />`

Comment: hmmm, @VPK , thanks, it remove from url but we have it in hidden input value? right?

Comment: Yes, right. On submit of your form, you can access the hidden variables on the server.

Comment: exactly what i want, please make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can use the JSP's `Implicit Objects`.

In your JSP, add hidden fields which map to the URL parameters like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="${param.page}" />
<input type="hidden" name="saved" value="${param.saved}" />
```

Here, the `param` implicit object will map a request parameter name to a single value. For more information, you can check the other features on the [DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaif).

Answer (score 0):

Java equivalent for PHP **$_GET['page']=2;** is

```
request.getParameter('page');
```

request is an implicit object in jsp.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need to set value not to get it!

Comment: Not sure of your use case but the java equivalent for setting the value is request.setAttribute("name","value");